# Set selected cell in UITableView initialization

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, selection

I want to set cell number 0 as the selected cell after `UITableView` is finished getting initialized?

I tried to do:

```
[cell setSelected:YES];
```

in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

but the cell color became black.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UITableView itself can manage the selection.  Try calling:

```
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
```